# Difference between AWS::Serverless::Function and AWS::Lambda::Function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am developing aws lambda function and I have an option of using one of these two function, but I don't find any good place where I can see the difference between these two. Which one should be used and in which case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a Serverless Function, and a Lambda Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953270/what-is-the-difference-between-a-serverless-function-and-a-lambda-function)

Answer (score 0):

AWS serverless application model i.e. AWS SAM is used to define a serverless application. You need to deploy this application on AWS lambda via s3.

SAM comes in action while testing the AWS Lambda Function locally because it's not easy to deploy and test on AWS Lambda every time you make a code change.

You can configure SAM on your IDE like eclipse, test and finalise the code then deploy it on Lambda.

For more info about sam https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/HOWTO.md